# Multiple javascript Ajax requests seem to work synchronous

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is my first part of code. I here have a list of all the api calls I need to do to retrieve data from the mySQL server.

```
function ProcessUrls() {
        requests = [];
        var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3' 'url4'];
        for(i=0;i<urls.length;i++)
        {
            requests.push(new ProcessUrl(urls[i]));
            console.log('Invoking the functions');
        }

    }
```

The 'Invoking the functions' log in the code above this line of text gets called 4 times almost instantly, as you would expect.

Here I process the urls and do the actual API calls:

```
function ProcessUrl(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.send(null);

    console.log('Function being called');

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            console.log('Done doing the API call');


            }
        }
    };
}
```

The "function being called" log gets called almost instantly 4 times as well, the problem is that the 'Done doing the API call' seems to run synchronous since the logs appears slowly one a time in a constant rhythm of ~0.5 seconds.

Is there a way to run these onreadystatechange parallel? This would speed up the process greatly.

Comment: I'm almost certain they would run in parallel. Why are you so certain that it isn't?

Comment: There's no problem with your code. It is pretty async. Investigate Dev Tools Network tab, the requests diagram. Maybe this is server side issue?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, we're looking in to the possibility that it might be a server-side issue.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with our product-environment! Thanks for your answers.